# How do I add 1 item decoration in a recyclerview?

Tags: android, divider, text-decorations

in the code below, I have currently added an item decoration between all my textviews in a recyclerview.

```
        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new HorizontalDividerItemDecoration.Builder(getContext()).color(Color.GRAY).margin(10).build());
```

I have a string array that I convert into a textview

```
        String[] titles = {"Explore","MyQuestions","MyAnswers","Calendar","Settings","Send FeedBack"};
```

It creates an item decoration between each textview, how do I create only 1  item decoration between calendar and send feedback?

Comment: where is your calendar and send feedback ? please provide more info about your question

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom ItemDecoration class and override the [RecyclerView.ItemDecoration#getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemDecoration.html#getItemOffsets(android.graphics.Rect,%20android.view.View,%20android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView,%20android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.State)) method.

you can get the position of the view via

```
parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view)
```

compare if the position corresponds the first item and set the top value of `outRect` to 0.